# How to Speed up a Google Drive API Search

Tags: python, google-drive-api

The below code takes about 2 seconds to query a specific folder containing ~5 google slide presentations within. 
Question: Is there a way to speed up / optimize the Google Drive API search? 
For my use case (drop down menu), 2 seconds is a little too long for live feedback. I think users would have an aneurysm ;)

```py
# all the credentials stuff....

mime = 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation'
gSlideFolder = 'folderId of presentations folder'
results = service.files().list(q=f"'{gSlideFolder}' in parents and mimeType='{mime}' and trashed=false",
                                  spaces='drive',
                                  fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
                                  ).execute()

items = results.get('files', [])

# Print results in items.....
```

I'm very new to this API...so it could be (is) something dumb. Apologies in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, there isn't anything you can do here. Your code is about as optimised as it can get.*

#### Further Information:

As far as your code goes, there's only one line of code that is interacting with the Google Drive API. For best practice reasons I would personally define your parameters separately and send them that way:

```py
mime = 'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation'
gSlideFolder = 'folderId of presentations folder'
q = f"'{gSlideFolder}' in parents and mimeType='{mime}' and trashed=false"
s = 'drive'
f = 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'

results = service.files().list(q=q, spaces=s, fields=f).execute()
```

However in terms of your actual API call there's not really anything you can do here - you're waiting for the request to be sent to Google's servers, Google's servers to process and run the request, and send the result back to your application. 2 seconds isn't that long for a `Files: list` request.

Comment: But...why? It takes the Drive web interface a fraction of a second to list hundreds of files. The same list takes over two seconds using the API. Do they have some secret super-API that they use for their interface?